# call href from PHP server. Need to avoid autotagging of localhost

Tags: php, html

When I use the below stmt,

```
print "<a href='www.google.com' > Click here </a>";
```

PHP server is automatically adding localhost to url i.e., localhost/www.google.com.

How can I avoid this? My PHP server is on the local host.

Thanks.

Comment: Post code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the protocol as the hyperlink.

```
https://www.google.com
```

This should fix the problem :)

Comment: Yup. A href that doesn't start with a protocol is assumed to be relative, and so current URL is taken into account.